# What is this subtitle format called?

Tags: video, subtitle, closed-captions

I found a subtitle that goes like this:

```
<transcript>
<text start="2.906" dur="3">TEXT 1</text>
<text start="7.907" dur="3.914">TEXT 2</text>
......
```

What is that format called?

Comment: I’ve never seen that. What is it from?

Comment: It's from a website, it could be their own custom format I guess. The file path said "timedtext" on it if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is Youtube's "Timed Text" transcript format. Based on [**W3C TTML**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timed_text) (see bottom example).

Your shown sample looks like an older version/layout format (eg: videos from 2011 have that similar layout, but 2017 transcripts look slightly different, since now using `timedtext format="3"`).

When you enable `CC` option on a video that (markup) transcript text is loaded. You can see this by checking "Network" requests in your browser's Developer Tools.

Open `timedtext>key=` link in new tab to view content of transcript text.

(see below [**image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywjNw.png)) :

[image]

**Edit :** 
PS: If you want it displayed similar to your posted style, in the `timedtext>key=` link just edit the ending of the URL from `&fmt=srv3` to become  `&fmt=srv1`.

Comment: This seems to be right, that you. Even though the subtitle came from another site, I guess it was from Google drive. Seems like the format can be changed but haven't figured out how yet.

Comment: @casolorz Changed how? You mean into another format like example SRT? If you want it displayed similar to your posted style just replace ending `&fmt=srv3` with `&fmt=srv1`.

Comment: Yeah that is what I was trying but I got errors with most things I tried, like vtt or srt. Right now the format was 1, 3 worked as well, but couldn't find anything else that worked.

Comment: Looks like if I put fmt=vtt it actually works, the browser just doesn't like it but I can get it using curl.

Answer (score 5):

Adding `&fmt=vtt` will actually convert the subtitle but the browser might give an error as this header is returned `Content-Type: text/xml` but the content is not xml.